# Create Spreadsheet for read and write using Node js

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, google-sheets

I Need to create a spreadsheet like a google sheet with user authentication. I have stuck with how to start this project because I couldn't find which NPM module needs to use.

so Kindly help anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: You could just use a Google sheet? There is an API, so you can control it yourself, probably easier than looking for something to do the same job :)

Comment: @Mikkel Thanks for your response. I have one doubt kindly clarify. I need excel sheet interface, suppose I am using this google sheet API  the same interface will be supported or not for my project.

Comment: Excel also has an online version, and I think you can write macros for that. But I can't confirm that it will work for you, as you haven't told us in detail what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on similar task few weeks ago.

So here is the mini help for you.

### 1. Read and follow [Node.js Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs).

Keep an eye on the next concepts like:

- **Scopes**

For example to get a value from a cell we can use [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Scopes for this method are (use 1 of these):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

in node.js it can be an array

```js
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
```

- **Token**

Once you run for the first time your `index.js` file the Terminal will ask you for authorization, on finish you will find a `token.json` in your work directory.

**If you change Scopes -> delete `token.json` from your directory**

- **SpreadsheetId**

When you create/edit your spreadsheet you get similar url
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqRe0ksSwgOoPO0C_mZE6opjS1TlsCU5g1HtkiiILuw/edit#gid=0`
**`1eqRe0ksSwgOoPO0C_mZE6opjS1TlsCU5g1HtkiiILuw`** is the ID

---

### 2. Create custom functions using [Google Sheets API Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

Example [how to get cell values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get):

```js
const sheets  = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
function getCellsValue(cells, callback){
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
  range: cells
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error #1001 : getCellsValue: ' + err);
    const output = res.data.values;
    if (output.length) {
      callback(output);
      return output;
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}

// here is the example use of this function which output values from D2:D13
getCellsValue("D2:D13", (e) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    console.log(e[i].toString());
  }
}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ', err.message);
})
```

---

### 3. Make a use of Try this API

This is very useful tool.

[image: Try this API]

In case you need more help just use Stackoverflow for more transparency.
Stackoverflow helps you when you make a very detailed question.

I hope this helped you and you can start your Google Sheets API journey.