# Download or Read uploaded Excel files from Google Drive using Node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Here is what I've done:

1. Setup the App on the Google developer console.
2. I can list all the files from the drive.
3. From one of these files, I want to read the excel file's data.
4. 

....

```
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: autho});
  try{
      const result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId: file.id});
     }
```

....

5. This approach throws an error of "This operation is not supported for this document".
6. So I tried downloading the file with the `file.get()`, and `file.export()` methods. Both of these methods return 403 error, the scopes that I've used in the App and console are basically almost all the scopes:

   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',]

Code to export the file:

```
const dest = fs.createWriteStream('temp/'+file.name);

const res = await drive.files.export({fileId: fileID, mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'},{responseType: 'stream'});
      

await new Promise((res, rej)=>{
            res.data.on('error', rej)
            .pipe(dest)
            .on('error', rej)
            .on('finish', res);
          });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719369/7924858

Comment: What this link shows, is the process to read/write Google Spreadsheets. As mentioned, I am trying to working with Excel sheets stored in Google Drive.

Comment: What is the exact mimetype of the file ON google drive that you are trying to download.  What does it say its mime type is.

Comment: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Its an MS Excel Sheet.

Comment: When you want to download the file except for Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on), it is required to use the method of "get" instead of "export". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. For this situation, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337805 In this sample, "get" or "export" methods are used for each mimeType. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: okay I'll try this.@Tanaike